# Class based views how to handle OneToOneField in a model

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have 2 models:

```python
class CompanyInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Location)


class Location(models.Model):
    address_1 = models.CharField(_("address"), max_length=128)
    address_2 = models.CharField(_("address cont'd"), max_length=128, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_("city"), max_length=64, default="")
    state = USStateField(_("state"), default="")
    zip_code = models.CharField(_("zip code"), max_length=5, default="")
```

When I use CBVs and prints out the form on the template. It shows name with an input field and address as a multiple choice selection.

Is there anyway in which I could convert the multiple choice to act as multiple input fields and the state to be multiple choice.

I figured I could have 2 form for these, but how would I incorporate a form inside of a form?

Also, the way in which the models and fields are must not be changed. For this example sure location fields could be in the company info, but I simply want how to do something similar when it doesn't make sense to include all these fields into the same model.

So, far only thing I can come up with is using function based views and just dealing with 2 forms at a time.

Here are my forms:

```python
class CompanyInfoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyInfo
        exclude = ['address']

class LocationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'
```

then class based views:

```python
class CompanyInfoCreate(CreateView):
    model = CompanyInfo
    form_class = CompanyInfoForm


class LocationCreate(CreateView):
    model = Location
    form_class = LocationForm
```

However, this is very helpful since these forms can only be done 1 at a time. I would like LocationView to be in place of the address location or of the sort.

Perhaps, these types of views have their strength in dealing with forms at an individual level.

Comment: Can you post the code to your CBVs as well?  What kind of form implementations you are doing. 
Generally you should use Model->ModelForm->FormView or Model->Create/update View

Comment: @ShauryaChaudhuri post is edit3. Don't like formatting on this comment area.

Comment: Do you need to handle two forms in a single view? Or handle a main form with several children forms in the same view?